# Как замедлить скорость цикла for?

Tags: c++, c

Мне нужно протестировать программу, но скорость слишком большая, что нужно сделать, что бы определенный цикл замедлился?

Comment: Вставьте в него [usleep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html)

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить, почему для **тестирования** нужно именно медленное выполнение?...

Comment: Типичная проблема XY. Приведите пример того, что вы пытаетесь делать. С вероятностью 99% ничего нигде замедлять не нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перевод ответа [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613664/5441023) (там есть и другие интересные вещи, но этот ответ показался наиболее полезным).

> В С++11 это можно сделать средствами стандартной библиотеки:
>
> ```
> #include <chrono>
> #include <thread>
>
> std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
> ```
>
> Понятно и читабельно, больше не нужно догадываться, какие единицы измерения
>   принимает функция `sleep()`.

Вставляете сие чудо 11 стандарта в тело цикла и вуаля. Можно использовать системные штуки для Windows и Linux соответственно:

```
#include "windows.h" 
Sleep(10);

#include <unistd.h>
usleep(10)
```

Для компиляторов, которые не в курсе про С++11, скорее всего придется поколдовать с функциями из С (заголовочный файл [<ctime>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)), как, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450965/5441023).